# Why does this OpenGL split screen code work? Unidentified texture?

Tags: opengl, textures

So I have an OpenGL program that does split screen. After doing research, my code looks like the following:

```
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   // 1
   // ----- Camera -----
   glViewport(0, 0, _windowW/2, _windowH);
   //  Tell OpenGL we want to manipulate the projection matrix
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   //  Undo previous transformations
   glLoadIdentity();
   //  Perspective transformation
   gluPerspective(_fov,_asp,_worldSize/_trolly,_trolly*_worldSize);
   // Move main camera
   _cameraLook[0] = _cameraLoc[0] + Sin(_th1)*Cos(_ph1)*_lookDistance;
   _cameraLook[1] = _cameraLoc[1] +           Sin(_ph1)*_lookDistance;
   _cameraLook[2] = _cameraLoc[2] + Cos(_th1)*Cos(_ph1)*_lookDistance;
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluLookAt(_cameraLoc[0], _cameraLoc[1], _cameraLoc[2], _cameraLook[0], _cameraLook[1], _cameraLook[2], 0, 1, 0);

   // ----- Drawing of scene -----
   drawSceneContents();

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,_framebufImg1);
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glTexCoord2f(0.25, 0.0); glVertex2f(-1.0, -1.0);
   glTexCoord2f(0.25, 1.0); glVertex2f(-1.0, +1.0);
   glTexCoord2f(0.75, 1.0); glVertex2f(+0.0, +1.0);
   glTexCoord2f(0.75, 0.0); glVertex2f(+0.0, -1.0);
   glEnd();

   // 2
   // ----- Camera -----
   glViewport(_windowW/2, 0, _windowW/2, _windowH);
   //  Tell OpenGL we want to manipulate the projection matrix
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   //  Undo previous transformations
   glLoadIdentity();
   //  Perspective transformation
   gluPerspective(_fov,_asp,_worldSize/_trolly,_trolly*_worldSize);

   // Move main camera
   _cameraLook[0] = _cameraLoc[4] + Sin(_th2)*Cos(_ph2)*_lookDistance;
   _cameraLook[1] = _cameraLoc[5] +           Sin(_ph2)*_lookDistance;
   _cameraLook[2] = _cameraLoc[6] + Cos(_th2)*Cos(_ph2)*_lookDistance;
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluLookAt(_cameraLoc[4], _cameraLoc[5], _cameraLoc[6], _cameraLook[0], _cameraLook[1], _cameraLook[2], 0, 1, 0);

   // ----- Drawing of scene -----
   drawSceneContents();

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,_framebufImg1);
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glTexCoord2f(0.25, 0.0); glVertex2f(-0.0, -1.0);
   glTexCoord2f(0.25, 1.0); glVertex2f(-0.0, +1.0);
   glTexCoord2f(0.75, 1.0); glVertex2f(+1.0, +1.0);
   glTexCoord2f(0.75, 0.0); glVertex2f(+1.0, -1.0);
   glEnd();
```

However, I don't understand why it is working and I must be missing something fundamental that OpenGL does. 
The part I don't understand is at the end of each 'screen', where I draw a textured quad (Last 5 lines of code). But where does this texture come from? Why does it happen to be a texture of the scene I am drawing for that screen? I never did glBindTexture or glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) anything, in fact before all of this code I can put a glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) and the code still works! How? How can I have a textured quad without ever mentioning texture in the code, aside from the texture coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: apply correction by *datenwolf*, well explained here => [10. The Viewport Does Not Clip or Scissor](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/)

According to the name of your texture (`_framebufImg1`), `drawSceneContents` should implement an offscreen rendering to a [FBO](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) which should have the texture attached as color attachment.

[glViewport](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glViewport.xml) map the projections coodinates to half the width of the screen, which allow you to draw the textured quad with the same vertices at 2 different places

```
glViewport(0, 0, _windowW/2, _windowH);
//first pass
glViewport(_windowW/2, 0, _windowW/2, _windowH);
//second pass
```

*without `drawSceneContents` details, I can't say more...*

Comment: Actually viewport only sets the mapping from NDC to window coordinates, but it doesn't *restrict* the rendering. Stuff can still appear outside of the viewport. You must use scissor testing in addition, so to restrict things within the viewport. `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST); glScissor(<same values as for glViewport>);`

Comment: @datenwolf: It's surely a bit stupid to try to get points like in a game on `stackexchange`, but indeed I'm learning lot's of stuff doing so.

Comment: @datenwolf: It should be worth noting that anything which goes through the normal vertex pipeline will get clipped and as a result never appear outside of the viewport. There are some corners cases where out-of-viewport writes might acually appear, but most of them are deprecated anyway. One of te few remaining things is just `glClear`.

Comment: @derhass: framebuffer copy operations like `glBlitFramebuffer` also are affected by scissor testing.

Comment: @datenwolf: Yes, you are right here. There are probably a few more. I did not want to say that your original comment was wrong or useless. I just felt the need of adding that those "out of viewport" writes are kind of special operations, and one can get away without scissor test in many situations. YMMV.